# Display or export gdal_translate exponential scaling equation

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdal-translate

I have an GeoTiff raster that contains elevation information at each pixel.  As OpenLayers 2 can't display GeoTiff, I convert it to a PNG image and have to apply an exponential scale so the resulting pixels aren't all mostly white after only the lower elevation levels if I just use the -scale option without the -exponent option.  However, I still need to know the elevation values at the pixels in the PNG image so I can display them via a color table lookup while mousing over the image.  Is there a way for either GDAL or QGIS to export or save the resulting non-linear scaling equation and/or exponential factors that gdal_translate determined when creating the resulting PNG image?

Here's how I'm using gdal_translate and my values:

gdal_translate -of PNG -ot Byte -scale 0.2 2219 0 255 -exponent 0.35 image.tif image.png

I have made a determination what the equation may be.  But, it would be good to know what it is exactly coming from gdal_translate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [GDAL Virtual Format Tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html) the equation used is:

```
(DstMax - DstMin) * pow( (SrcValue - SrcMin) / (SrcMax - SrcMin), Exponent) + DstMin
```